# How to choose ML model based on the data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, methodology

I want to know when I should choose linear models like linear, polynomial, lasso , rigid regression and non linear models like cart, random forest, boosting algorithms. what are the factors i should consider like correlation, scatter plots etc when choosing the model?

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of question that the whole 600-page statistics textbooks are written about. In this limited space let me give you some bullet points.

1] Everything begins with exploratory data analysis. You visualize the data, in 2D, 3D, run some simple (non-)parametric tests and form your opinion about what's going on. You build your intuition.

2] You look at the sample size. If the ratio of observations to estimated parameters is 10 or 20 forget about CART or boosting algorithms. "Data mining" is called so for a reason. It's when you get dealt a huge data set, you are swimming in information and you have to make sense of it somehow.

3] Non-linear relationships between $Y$ and $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_p$ **can** be captured by linear regression or lasso. You just add $X_1^k$, $X_2^k$, ..., $X_p^k$ and/or $log(X_1)$, $log(X_2)$, ..., $log(X_p)$ as predictors.

4] Many modeling frameworks **must** be tried for each problem. Within each of them, the "optimal model" must be identified using statistical significance of parameters or an objective model selection criterion.

5] To identify the optimal modeling framework (e.g. regression vs CART vs neural network), you use an objective model selection criterion, e.g. [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)), [Akaike Information Criterion (AIC)](http://www.stanfordphd.com/AIC.html) or [Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC)](http://www.stanfordphd.com/BIC.html).

6] "Goodness of fit diagnostics" must be run after whatever modeling decision you have made.